# Как добавить class = "active" к активному элементу меню

Tags: php

В шаблоне есть код для меню, которое берется из БД.

```
<div class="container-fluid p-0">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top">
    <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">
        <img src="/images/Brand.png"  height="50" alt="logo">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav  align-content-between w-100">
            {foreach $menu as $item}
                {if ($item->isActive)}
                    <li class="nav-item m-auto active">
                        <a href="{$item->url}{$item->id}/" class="nav-link">{$item->label}</a>
                    </li>
                {/if}
            {/foreach}
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Как сделать так что бы к тегу

добавлялся class = "active" если пользователь находится на данной странице?
{if ($item->isActive)} это проверка, выводить этот пункт меню или нет.
Если понадобится код с контроллера

```
function indexAction($smarty){
$menu = getItemsMenu();
$partners = getItemsPartners();

$smarty->assign('menu', $menu);
$smarty->assign('partners', $partners);
$smarty->assign('pageTitle', 'ТМТ Энерго');

loadTemplate($smarty, 'mainHeader');
loadTemplate($smarty, 'index');
loadTemplate($smarty, 'footer');
```

}

Используется шаблонизатор смарти, можно показать как это сделать в phtml и php, дальше сам разберусь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы проверял на совпадение ссылки с адресом страницы.
Я не знаю как работать со Смарти,  принцип опишу, если что поправишь как нужно.

```
{foreach $menu as $item}
    {set elem_href = $item->url . $item->id}
    {if ($item->isActive)}
        {set ative = ''}
        {if elem_href == this_url}
            {set ative = 'active'}
        {/if}
        <li class="nav-item m-auto {active}">
            <a href="elem_href/" class="nav-link">{$item->label}</a>
        </li>
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Как-то так. `this_url` это адрес текущей страницы. Если нельзя его получить из шаблонизатора (всяко бывает), передай его из контроллера. И подставляй `active` тому элементу, внутри которого у ссылки `href` совпадает с текущим адресом.

P.S. `$item->isActive` я не понял что у тебя делает и связан ли он как-то с... думаю, его можно будет убрать, если связан.

Comment: Во всех других контроллерах, отвечающих за другие страницы есть такая строка `$itemId = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) ? filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) : null;
    if (!$itemId) {
        exit ();
    }`

Comment: в шаблон я добавил `$itemId` и сделал такую проверку `<li class="nav-item m-auto {if $item->id == $itemId}active{/if} ">` на всех страницах кроме главной это работает. На главной  если вставить эту строку то мне ничего не показывает, т.е. вообще главная страница не отображается.

Comment: @НиколайГромов что значит "не отображается"? Пункт меню не выделяется ативным?

Comment: нет страница полностью не отображается из-за `if (!$itemId) { exit (); }`, а не главной он всегда равен NULL

Comment: @НиколайГромов я не знаю при чём тут `$itemId`, я говорил про URL страницы и `href`

Comment: Все разобрался, спасибо.

Comment: @НиколайГромов если помогло, не забудь отметить ответ правильным.

Comment: мне написало голос участников с репутацией ниже 15 учитывается, но не отображается.